# SQL pivot column names and organize by date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table as such:

```
date       | page
-----      |-----
2018-01-01 | good
2018-01-01 | good
2018-01-01 | good
2018-01-01 | bad
2018-01-02 | good
```

How do I organize by the values in the page column by date as such:

```
date       | good | bad
-----      |------|----
2018-01-01 | 3    | 1
2018-01-02 | 1    | 0
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Just did @YogeshSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *conditional* aggregation :

```
select date, 
       sum(case when page = 'good' then 1 else 0 end) as good, 
       sum(case when page = 'bad' then 1 else 0 end) as bad
from table t
group by date;
```

However, MySQL has shorthand for this :

```
select date, 
       sum( page = 'good') as good, 
       sum( page = 'bad' ) as bad
from table t
group by date;
```

Comment: So how can this scale? For example, what if there are more than two states, i.e. "good", "great", and "bad"?

Comment: @sshah98. . . If you have a known `page`s then you can just simply write `sum()`s else you would need to write dynamic pivot query for that.

Answer (score 1):

This can work just add a case inside sum function:

```
select date, 
       sum( case when page = 'good' then 1 else 0 end) as good, 
       sum( case when page = 'bad' then 1 else 0 end ) as bad 
from table t 
group by date
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pivot` table as,

```
 create table #pivot(date date,page varchar(20))
 insert into #pivot values
 ('2018-01-01','good')
 ,('2018-01-01','good')
 ,('2018-01-01','good')
 ,('2018-01-01','bad')
 ,('2018-01-02','good')

 select date,good,bad from(  
 select date, page from #pivot 
 ) f
 pivot
( count(page) for page in (good,bad)
) p
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what platform you are using but if it is in Oracle this will do the same.

```
select date, sum(decode(page,'good',1,0)) as good, sum(decode(page,'bad',1,0)) as bad              
from table t                                                                       
group by date;
```